# Issue with MailChimp delete API?

Tags: mailchimp

For DELETE APIs, if we hit the API with invalid data, the API responds with proper error message. If we use the same HTTP connection object to hit another API, the request fails.

This issue is not seen for Create or Update APIs. Also if the Delete request is sent with valid data, then using the same HTTP connection object for next request works fine.
Please note that this behavior has implications for connection pooling in client applications, and we were just wondering if its known issue and if there is any available workaround.